# "Свойственный ему" или "свойственный себе"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

> Учитель раскусил аферу и захотел в свойственной **себе/ему** манере выставить ученика смешным.

Какое слово лучше употребить, или оба варианта равноправны?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из словаря:

СВОЙСТВЕННЫЙ,  **кому-чему**. Составляющий чьё-л. свойство, присущий кому-, чему-л., характерный для кого-л. Изобразить **со свойственным ему** талантом. Встречать **со свойственным ей** радушием.

"Свойственный себе" употребляется редко, **возможно,  выражение содержит тавтологию (свой, себе),** вот единственный пример из Корпуса: Древо, поливаемое ежедневно, не высохнет, но принесет **свойственный себе** плод. [епископ Игнатий (Брянчанинов). Отечник (1863)]  Вероятно, "тавтология" в данном случае используется в качестве усилительного средства.

Пример **с личным местоимением (их большинство):**
Как только король начал говорить громко и быстро, все королевское достоинство мгновенно оставило его, и он, сам не замечая, перешел в с**войственный ему** тон добродушной фамильярности. [Л. Н. Толстой. Война и мир. Том третий (1867-1869)]

Answer (score 1):

Здесь лучше "ему". "Свойственный себе" на слух плохо воспринимается. Может, потому, что "свойственный" - и без того имеет оттенок притяжательности, "себе" уже избыточно. А может, потому, что "свойственный кому-либо" - выражение более или менее устоявшееся.